# \includegraphics cant find path

Tags: graphics

I am currently on TeXWorks trying to specify the path of the pdf file I want to be shown. I have looked at previous questions and none of the formats seem to work. This is what I have:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=2.0in]{"C:/Users/myker/Drexel University/Steven Weber 
-Drexel-ILACI-Shared/InstituteBibDocFigSlide/Figs-Misc/Fig-
SignatureScan.pdf"}
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure}
```

I included the entire path to the file I want. I ended up getting the image I want but the path of the file is getting partially printed into the document. Its printing: "University/Steven Weber - 
Drexel-ILACI-Shared/InstituteBibDocFigSlide/Figs-Misc/Fig-SignatureScan.bb" above my image

Comment: Try with a path that does not contain spaces, use a relative path or try the package https://ctan.org/pkg/grffile?lang=en

Comment: I can't change the path. I already added 
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
and it still won't work.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=2.0in]{C:/Use/Simple/Directory/Names/Fig-
SignatureScan}` (without quoting and without  extension) or  use a relative path, for instance  `\includegraphics[width=2.0in]{../Names/Fig-SignatureScan}` (of course, assuming that the main .tex file is inside a sister directory of "Names").

Comment: The picture now shows up but the path of the picture gets printed in text above it. Is there a way to get rid of this?