# How to include an image whose path is set by a user macro?

Tags: macros, graphics, external-files

Assume the following scenario. Some user is required to complete a macro `ImagePath{}` in order to automatically include an image at some predefined place of the document. No hypothesis is done about its extension. The MWE below fails to compile with error *! LaTeX Error: File `images/logo.png' not found.* even if the file **does** exist.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\ImagePath#1{\def\@ImagePath{#1}}
\def\printImagePath{\@ImagePath}
\makeatother
\ImagePath{images/logo.png}
\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{\printImagePath}{
    \includegraphics{\printImagePath}
}{
    File \texttt{\printImagePath} does not exist
}
\end{document}
```

Surprisingly, if one imposes the extension, e.g. PNG, there is no more compilation error :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\ImagePath#1{\def\@ImagePath{#1}}
\def\printImagePath{\@ImagePath}
\makeatother
\ImagePath{logo}
\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{\printImagePath.png}{
    \includegraphics{\printImagePath.png}
}{
    File \texttt{\printImagePath.png} does not exist
}
\end{document}
```

Thus, is there a way to get the full image path from the user, whatever the extension is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the details of the implementation, but as far as I know, `\includegraphics` expands its argument *only once* before trying to include the image. (I assume, this is a side effect of allowing active characters and such in the file name.)

If you design your macro in such a way that the macro used in `\includegraphics` immediately contains the image path, it works.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\ImagePath#1{\def\theimagepath{#1}}

\ImagePath{images/logo.png}

\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{\theimagepath}{
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{\theimagepath}
}{
    File \texttt{\theimagepath} does not exist
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240160/48973).

Comment: Based on the answer you point out, `\meaning\printImagePath` produces _macro:->\@ImagePath_, which is not `images/logo.png` as expected.

Comment: By the way, this solution is far better than mine since it does not rely on any other packages. One even can avoid `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution (thanks to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411007/includegraphics-cant-find-path?rq=1#comment1026064_411007)), but I can't figure out how it works: loading `grffile` package in the preamble prevents from the compilation error…

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\ImagePath#1{\def\@ImagePath{#1}}
\def\printImagePath{\@ImagePath}
\makeatother
\ImagePath{images/logo.png}
\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{\printImagePath}{
    \includegraphics{\printImagePath}
}{
    File \texttt{\printImagePath} does not exist
}
\end{document}
```

Somebody able to explain why this works can comment this post.